# Guess features needed to provide function upon void-function error

Tags: error-handling

#### Question

How do I run code before any `void-function` error is signaled? I have a feeling I can use advising for this, but I don't know what exactly I need to advise.

#### What I want to achieve

Before any `void-function` error is raised, I'd like emacs to try to load existing features that are likely to provide that function. For example, if the function `evil-magit-init` is called and is not already defined, I'd like emacs to check the load-path, notice that the feature `evil-magit` has a name that is a prefix for `evil-magit-init`, load it and check if `evil-magit-init` is defined and then, if it is, load `evil-magit` and then try calling `evil-magit-init` again. Essentially, this is an alternative to autoloading.

#### What I tried

As a model I looked towards [auto-define](https://github.com/emacsattic/auto-define/blob/master/auto-define.el), a package that tries to define non-existing functions that follow a pattern "on-the-fly". For example, it would take a function such as `prog4` and define it based on what `prog1` and `prog2` do.

I tried to emulate this with the following:

```
(defun eval@try-load-feature (orig-fn &rest args)
  "Try to load feature that could contain function."
  (condition-case err
      (apply orig-fn args)
    (void-function
     (iter
      (with (fname (cadr err)))
      (initially (message "Triggering advice with %s!!!" (cadr err)))
      (for feature (xl-possible-features fname))
      (require feature)
      (when (fboundp fname)
       (message "Autoloading %s..." feature)
       (return (apply orig-fn args)))
      (else (signal (car err) (cdr err)))))))
(advice-add 'eval :around (function eval@try-load-feature) nil)

;; (xl-possible-features 'evil-magit-init) => (evil-magit evil)
(defun xl-possible-features (fn)
  "Return a list of possible features available for FN"
  (loopy (with (fname (symbol-name fn)))
     (list path load-path)
     (expr base (f-base path))
     (expr feature (intern base))
     (when (s-prefix-p base fname)
       (collect possible feature))
     (finally-return (seq-sort-by (-compose #'length #'symbol-name) #'> possible))))
```

#### What Actually Happened

My solution only caught the `void-function` error with functions that seemed to use `eval`. Such as `eval-last-sexp`. However, it does not work for `void-function` errors from forms not evaluated in a buffer. As I mentioned I'd like to intercept `void-function` errors raised from anywhere.

Comment: May I ask your motivation for this?  It just sounds like a bad idea to me.  If this is possible at all, I suspect it's going to introduce substantial inefficiencies.  I would expect that by the time Emacs is raising a void-function error, the opportunity to call a function has passed -- and if that's the case, you'd instead need to act *before* every single function call (if that's even possible to do) to test whether or not that error is *going* to happen...

Comment: My motivation is not to have to use Emacs's autoload system. Instead of relying on well-placed autoload cookies and having to maintain an autoloads file, I wanted to explore the possibility of relying on package prefixes. As for the efficiences, I don't necessarily think it would be inefficient as this would only happen during `void-function` errors--my example demonstrates how I could do this when advising a single function. I agree that if I needed to act before every function call I'd run into problems, but that's not what I'm going for.

Comment: I think you'll need to do this in C code.